# using a sql script storaged in gcs on bigquery

Tags: bash, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use a `.sql` file saved on Google Cloud Storage to query `BigQuery`

I'm trying with the `bq` command [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#global_flags) without success.

`bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < gs://bucket/path-to-file/file.sql`

Is the command misused ?

Comment: What do you have as an output from that command? Do you have anything as an example of table creation in file.sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use both:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql
```

and

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false
```

Check whether you have access to that bucket in Storage and copy the file to a local folder if it's not so large:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/path-to-file/file.sql .
```

Try to apply that file

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql << file.sql
```

You can try such trick if the file isn't large:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql "$(gsutil cat gs://bucket/path-to-file/file.sql)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The file with script should be local to your gcloud instance
Assuming file.sql is in your working directory - below example would work

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < file.sql
```

So, in your case you need to use gsutil to first load file.sql from GCS to your directory

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/path-to-file/file.sql .
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < file.sql
```